# Change auto import format in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, ide, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2016.3 and currently working on typescript based project.

Right now auto import will generate something like this:

```
import {xxx} from "yyy"
```

I want to change the format to

```
import { xxx } from 'yyy'
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

2016.3.*:

- in `Settings | Code Style | Typescript | Spaces`, enable `Within / ES6 import/export braces`
- in `Settings | Code Style | Typescript | Other`, set `Quote marks:` to **Single quotes**

2017.1.*:

- in `Settings | Code Style | Typescript | Spaces`, enable `Within / ES6 import/export braces`
- in `Settings | Code Style | Typescript | Punctuation`, set `Use` to **single**

Comment: Seems it has been changed for "Quote Marks". You can find it in: `Settings | Code Style | Typescript | Punctuation `.

Comment: Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | spaces tab .. scroll down to "within" group and tick .. ES6 import/export braces

Comment: In `2022.2.3`, `Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Spaces` -> `Within / ES6 import/export braces` and `Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Punctuation` -> `Use _ quotes / single`

Comment: Soooo darn helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

You can change this in:

> Settings | Code Style | Typescript | Other

Select *Single quote* for *Quote marks* in *Generated code* section